# Generalization of differentiability/smoothness class "$C^n$" notation

Tags: continuity, notation, smooth-functions

Is there any notion, in the literature, of generalizing the notation $C^n$ where $n \in \mathbb{z}$, which represents smoothness (or, more precisely, existence and continuity of the $n$th derivative), to $C^x$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{+} - \frac{1}{2}$? For example, maybe $C^{1/2}$ would represent the functions which are at least once-differentiable but would not imply anything about its continuity, let alone further differentiability, on the input set (which I have suppressed). That seems like a natural enough specification of meaning for that particular 'index'. I know that there are different types of 'continuity' and that there is probably no complete canonical list of them, but they do form a hierarchy and we should be able to manually assign indices to them in, I hope, a bijective manner (even if there is no means by which to specify a general rule for such assignments). Actually, it is a partially-ordered hierarchy, so one particular path would have to be taken, but that is still pretty fine to me; alternatively, we could introduce another index which determines the path through the continuities taken, or something like that.

I recognize that there are separate notations (I have seen $D^n$ for the class of $n$-times-differentiable functions, for example), but that is just a matter of there existing two separate notations which sometimes coïncide.

Comment: There is the space $C^{n,\alpha}$ of functions, where each function is such that its $n$'th derivative is [Hölder continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) with exponent $\alpha$ with $0 < \alpha \leq 1$ (on a specified compact set; or more generally, on the closure of some specified set but in this case we additionally require the $n$'th derivative to be bounded), which gives a strictly decreasing $\alpha$-indexed "sequence" of function spaces between the spaces $C^n$ and $C^{n+1}.$ **(continued)**

Comment: For greater refinement and stratification, the power functions $t^{\alpha}$ associated with being ${\alpha}$-Hölder continuity can be replaced by arbitrary [moduli of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_of_continuity) $\omega$ to give the [spaces $C^{n,\omega}$](https://ems.press/journals/rmi/articles/4645) of functions. See [Definition of the space of Hölder continuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2138688/13130) *AND* **(continued)**

Comment: [Definitions of terms tied to continuous functions and Holder spaces and their norms in PDE theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4365307/13130) *AND* [Confused about which Hölder spaces are Banach](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180371/13130) *AND* [Characterization of $C^{k,\alpha}$ functions with Hölder continuous derivatives) through Taylor estimates](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2491044/13130).